# Swift: Control Navigation Bar displayMode

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to figure out how to programatically control the default behaviour that happens when you scroll up on a Navigation View's Child View.

On scroll the Navigation Bar's black title (`.large`) is hidden by the Navigation Bar's  `.inline` title that slowly fades in. GIF attached.

[image]

However I already have a title for my page (the white text) that appears further down. Is there a way to hide the default black title, and control when that `.inline` title fades in. I ask because I want to replicate that Navigation Bar scroll effect, except I only want that `.inline` title to begin fading in once the white title goes off screen. I've attempted to illustrate this in the below image.

[image]

I think I have to dip into UIKit for this level of customisability so I've begun screwing around with `UINavigationBar.appearance()` to hide the `.large` Navigation Bar title. But I'm not sure how to control when and how the Navigation Bar appears. I assume I have to use the scroll position to trigger that animation.

I'm pretty new to Swift so help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing to do in this case is to use the custom title view in the navigation bar, and not use the default navigation title at all.

```swift
NavigationView { 
    YourView()
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                Text("Title").opacity(titleOpacity)
            }
        }
}
```

You will need to calculate the value of `titleOpacity`  yourself by observing the offset value of the scroll view, and adjusting the parameters accordingly.

```swift
@State private var scrollOffset: CGFloat = 0

private var titleOpacity: Double {
    // calculate the opacity based of current scroll view offset
}
```

Comment: I assume I will also need to adjust the `.toolbar`s opacity, as well also. How am I able to control that?

Comment: I have found [this aricle](https://medium.com/swlh/custom-navigationview-bar-in-swiftui-4b782eb68e94) that may be helpful

Comment: I don't believe this achieves what I'm looking for.